# Why failed to read /dev/urandom in a loop

Tags: shell

#### shell script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

for i in {1..1000}; do
    head -c 10000 /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-1' | head -0 \
        && echo -n . \
        || { echo -e "\nNum $i, Unknown error!"; break; }
    sleep 0.1
done
```

#### Description

- the only key command is

  ```bsh
  head -c 10000 /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-1' | head -0
  ```
- this script broke after a few seconds

  ```
  .......................................
  Num 40, Unknown error!
  ```

#### Issue

- why this script aborted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to obtain exit code of a process, use `$?`. Replace your error reporting with:

```
echo -e "\nNum $i, error: $?"; break;
```

This will show that when your script exits, a program exits with code 141.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880606/socket-connection-getting-closed-abruptly-with-code-141) says code 141 means the process was killed with `SIGPIPE`.

Since you are asking `head` to read 0 lines, it could be exiting before the preceding programs have written anything to their output streams, resulting in an error.

One way of addressing this is to delay the final head slightly:

```
set -euo pipefail

for i in {1..1000}; do
    if head -c 10000 /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-1' | (sleep 0 && head -0) ; then
    echo -n . 
    else
     echo -e "\nNum $i, error: $?"; break; 
     fi
    sleep 0.1
done
```